Firebase Analytics condition operator for user properties
When creating an audience in Firebase, and selecting a custom user property (which is a string), do the filter condition operators <> > = etc compare lexographically? Or do they work only on numbers?
For example: will a user property value 2024-04-01 compare as greater than 2024-03-31 if using the > operator?
